# Translation of "at the same time as"

Tags: traduction, prépositions, indications-de-temps

The concert will take place at the same time as the dance.

> Le concert aura lieu ____ la danse.

Should we use "au même temps que"? Or "en même temps que"? There is the expression "en même temps" meaning "at the same time", but in this case I suspect we have to use *au*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You suspect wrong, although *au même temps* is not completely wrong, just very outdated. The correct sentence in current French is:

> Le concert aura lieu [en même temps](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_m%C3%AAme_temps) que la danse.

With *au*, you might use:

> Le concert aura lieu [au même moment](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_m%C3%AAme_moment) que la danse.